# Prevent Postback after opening jQuery dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, jquery-dialog

Page:

```
<body>
 <form id="frmLogin" runat="server">  
  <asp:Button ID="btnClick" OnClientClick="openConfirmDialog();" OnClick="PopulateLabel"  runat="server"/>
  <div id="divDialog"></div>
  <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </form>
</body>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#divDialog").dialog({autoOpen: false,
                     buttons: { "Ok": function()
                                      { 
                                         $(this).dialog("close");
                                      },
                                "Cancel": function()
                                      { 
                                          $(this).dialog("close");
                                      }
                              } 
                   });
 });

 function openConfirmDialog()
 {
  $("#divDialog").dialog("open");
 }
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    lblText.Text = "";
 }

protected void PopulateLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    lblText.Text = "Hello";
 }
```

This code opens me a dialog box with Ok and Cancel button but it do not wait for user activity and post the page immediately and the label gets populated. I need to call the c# function based on user activity. If user clicks "Ok" label should get populated and if user clicks "Cancel" it should not call the c# function. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another button and used the jQuery click() event to trigger new button's click event which will in turn trigger the respective event handler in C#

Answer (score 4):

First, to prevent the page from immediately posting back to the server, you need to cancel the default behavior of the `click` event by returning `false` from your handler:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" OnClick="PopulateLabel"
    OnClientClick="openConfirmDialog(); return false;" />
```

Next, you need to perform the postback yourself when your `Ok` button is clicked:

```
$("#divDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close");
            __doPostBack("btnClick", "");
        },
        "Cancel": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the first argument to `__doPostBack()` is the *name* of the control (its `UniqueID` in ASP.NET terminology). Since the button is a direct child of the `<form>` element, we can hardcode its `id` in the `__doPostBack()` call, but things will get more complicated if it resides in a container hierarchy. In that case, you can use [ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) to generate the appropriate call to `__doPostBack()`.

**EDIT:** Since your page does not contain any postback-enabled control, `__doPostBack()` won't be defined on the client side. To work around that problem, you can use a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control instead of a [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx) control.

Comment: __doPostBack("btnClick", ""); is not calling my c# function

Comment: @Sri Kumar, what's the `name` attribute of your button (in the rendered page source)?

Comment: btnClick is my button ID and btnClick is the name

Comment: @Sri Kumar, then that should work, your `PopulateLabel()` function should be called on postback. Are you doing something special in the `RaisePostBackEvent()` method of your page?

Comment: I get this error in Error Console "__doPostBack is not defined" and I read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480362/dopostback-is-not-defined but I do not understand what control has to be added?

Comment: Can you do `RegisterRequiresPostback(btnClick);` during your page's `PreRender` phase and check if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Added Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(btnClick); in Pageload and Error : Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack can only be called on controls that implement IPostBackDataHandler

Comment: That's it, you need to use a postback-aware control, like a `LinkButton` instead of your `Button` control, and `__doPostback()` will be defined.

Comment: Problem here I cannot go for a link. It will be a button :(

Comment: Then you might want to add a hidden `LinkButton` to your page, something like `<asp:LinkButton ID="postBackEnabler" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />`

Comment: I tried to have another button with visibility as false and used to trigger  $("btnHiddenClick").click(); its click event but this also fails as the jQuery is not trigger its respective event