# DotNetOpenAuth provider don't work in ie11 on https

Tags: https, dotnetopenauth, internet-explorer-11

The site of our Openid provider revealed a problem with ie 11.
After login, when the provider is required to make the return redirect page is reloaded and again we find ourselves on the page, login and password.
After several attempts to get this [error](http://habrastorage.org/storage3/3f6/ac8/6c5/3f6ac86c54cd9072bd9a134bad2ae40a.png).

The lines on which the error occurs:

```
if (ProviderEndpoint.PendingAuthenticationRequest.IsDirectedIdentity) {
        ProviderEndpoint.PendingAuthenticationRequest.LocalIdentifier = Code.Util.BuildIdentityUrl(); 
}
```

What is interesting, this problem occurs only when using https. When http everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is a result of the IE11 [new User Agent String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2013/07/02/troubleshooting-and-fixing-session-cookie-problems-in-ie11.aspx). 
MS is already have a [patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939) for .Net Framework 4, but it didn't work for me because I have .Net Framework 4.5 on the server while provider is using .Net Framework 4.0. 
So I can't install the patch properly ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485339/dopostback-failing-in-ie-11-windows-8-1/19002263#19002263)).

I temporarily solved this issue by using the value of **UseCookies** for the **cookieless** attribute in web.config file (<authentication><forms> section)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is also the solution for a custom MembershipProvider we use, which is derived from System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.