# .NET not picking up browser files so IE11 is not detected

Tags: .net, file, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, browser-detection

I have created an ie11.browser file and added it to my Windows server hoping .NET will start detecting IE11 instead of assuming a default browser without Javascript capability. Read more about this issue here: [doPostback failing in IE 11+ Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485339/dopostback-failing-in-ie-11-windows-8-1)

- I installed Microsoft hotfix [2836939](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2836939/en-us)
- I Added [Sistemas-infoe's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485339/dopostback-failing-in-ie-11-windows-8-1) ie11.browser file to the App_Browsers folder
- I restarted IIS
- I restarted the entire server
- I added the ie11.browser file to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers and to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework**64**\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers
- I ran aspnet_regbrowsers -i for both locations
- I reset IIS
- I restarted the server
- I ran aspnet_regbrowser -u for both locations (and -i again afterwards)
- I disabled "hide extensions for know file types" hoping my browser file would have a hidden txt extension.

But somehow IE11 just doesn't get detected and it seems the browser files aren't read.

Is there any logging available that gives more info about this situation? I am completely in the dark as to why .NET still won't detect IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow asking stuff on Stackoverflow always gets me a solution. In half of the cases someone answers my question in the other half I come up with an answer myself five minutes after I posted the question.

I re-installed the update and rebooted again and somehow the browser is now detected. I have still no clue why this took more than two reboots.

Comment: For me, custom browser files actually interfered with the hotfix until I removed them, and then everything worked.