# Server control width won't apply with IE11 ?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net-4.0, cross-browser

I have this simple server control with a valid `Width` attribute :  ( asp.net 4 , vs2010 )

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TXT_UserName" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>`
On all browsers (`all + ie<11`) it does render as it should with the appropriate `Width`

But with ie11 ( windows 8.1 ) it wont render as it should : (it's even not in the view source ) :

[image]

Here is how I see it in other browsers ( including `ie<11`)

[image]

I've already added (*for past problems which are now solved*) the `App_Browsers` folder with the appropriate files  for compatibility with IE versions :

[image]

**Question :**

Why I'm not seeing the width attribute and how can I fix it ?

Comment: My same issue was solved with the latest ie.browser suggestions from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19585339/1364780 . I know you already mentioned this, but you may want to doublecheck against the ie.browser code posted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...can't reproduce your error, and I *don't* have any special `App_Browser` folder, though I'm on *VS2012 (4.5)*:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="styletextbox1" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Render Source (ie11):

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$styletextbox1" type="text" id="MainContent_styletextbox1" style="width:250px;" />
```

Dev tools (ie11):

[image: screenshot of ie11 dev tools]

So our *diff* are:

- VS2012
- 4.5
- App_Browser

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed.
Your App_Browsers folder should contain:
firefox.browser, ie.browser, and ie11.browser

The ie11.browser content:

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
    <identification>
        <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
        <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
    </identification>

    <capture>
        <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
    </capture>

    <capabilities>
        <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
        <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
        <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
        <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
        <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
        <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
        <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
        <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
        <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
        <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
        <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>

<!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
<browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
    <identification>
        <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
        <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
        <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
        <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
        <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
        <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
        <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
        <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
        <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
        <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
        <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
        <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
        <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
        <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
        <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
        <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
        <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
</browsers>
```