# ASP.Net update panel is not working in browser IE11

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel, internet-explorer-11

Asp .net `ajax updatepanel` working fine in local environment in browser `I11`.

But same not worked in live server. ( remote server)

When changing compatibility view in browser works fine.

In `IE11` update panel  not worked and not throws any error.

I have noted following lines are not created in IE11 browser view source.

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [doPostback failing in IE 11+ Windows 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485339/dopostback-failing-in-ie-11-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax `updatepanel and __doPostback()` function issue resolved in browser `IE10,IE11`.

Issue has fixed, follow the below steps:

1. Enable the app_browser folder in solution explorer.
2. Create the file with name "`ie.browser`"
3. Copy the below code

   ```
   <browsers>
     <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4325) -->
     <browser id="IE6Plus" parentID="IE">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="^[6-9]|\d{2,}$" />
       </identification>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
         <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
         <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
         <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
         <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
         <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
         <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
         <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
         <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
         <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
         <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
         <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
         <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
         <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
         <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;) -->
     <browser id="IE6to9" parentID="IE6Plus">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="^[6-9]$" />
       </identification>
     </browser>

     <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0;) -->
     <browser id="IE7" parentID="IE6to9">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="^7$" />
       </identification>
       <capabilities>
         <capability name="jscriptversion" value="5.7" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) -->
     <browser id="IE8" parentID="IE6to9">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="^8$" />
       </identification>
       <capabilities>
         <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <!-- Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729) -->
     <browser id="IE9" parentID="IE6to9">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="^9$" />
       </identification>
       <capabilities>
         <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0) -->
     <browser id="IE10Plus" parentID="IE6Plus">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="\d{2,}" />
       </identification>
       <capabilities>
         <capability name="jscriptversion" value="6.0" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
       <identification>
         <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
         <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
       </identification>

       <capture>
         <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
       </capture>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
         <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
         <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
         <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
         <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
         <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
         <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
         <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
         <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
         <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
         <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>


     <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
     <browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
       </identification>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
         <capability name="jscriptversion" value="5.6" />
         <capability name="javascript" value="true" />
         <capability name="javascriptversion" value="1.5" />
         <capability name="msdomversion" value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
         <capability name="w3cdomversion" value="1.0" />
         <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
         <capability name="activexcontrols" value="true" />
         <capability name="backgroundsounds" value="true" />
         <capability name="cookies" value="true" />
         <capability name="frames" value="true" />
         <capability name="javaapplets" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsCallback" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsFileUpload" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsVCard" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsXmlHttp" value="true" />
         <capability name="tables" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute" value="true" />
         <capability name="tagwriter" value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
         <capability name="vbscript" value="true" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <!-- Below is older entry -->

     <browser id="IE5to9" parentID="IE">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="^[5-9]|[1-9]\d+" />
       </identification>

       <capture>
       </capture>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="activexcontrols"     value="true" />
         <capability name="backgroundsounds"    value="true" />
         <capability name="cookies"             value="true" />
         <capability name="css1"                value="true" />
         <capability name="css2"                value="true" />
         <capability name="ecmascriptversion"   value="1.2" />
         <capability name="frames"              value="true" />
         <capability name="javaapplets"         value="true" />
         <capability name="javascript"          value="true" />
         <capability name="jscriptversion"      value="5.0" />
         <capability name="msdomversion"        value="${majorversion}${minorversion}" />
         <capability name="supportsCallback"    value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsFileUpload"  value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsVCard"       value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"     value="true" />
         <capability name="tables"              value="true" />
         <capability name="tagwriter"           value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
         <capability name="vbscript"            value="true" />
         <capability name="w3cdomversion"       value="1.0" />
         <capability name="xml"                 value="true" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>


     <browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
       <identification>
         <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
         <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
       </identification>

       <capture>
         <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
       </capture>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
         <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
         <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
         <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
         <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
         <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
         <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
         <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
         <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
         <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
         <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
     <browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
       <identification>
         <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
       </identification>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
         <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
         <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
         <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
         <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
         <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
         <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
         <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
         <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
         <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
         <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
         <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
         <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
         <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
         <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
         <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
       </capabilities>
     </browser>

     <gateway id="IEbeta" parentID="IE">
       <identification>
         <capability name="letters" match="^([bB]|ab)" />
       </identification>

       <capture>
       </capture>

       <capabilities>
         <capability name="beta"    value="true" />
       </capabilities>
     </gateway>
   </browsers>
   ```

Comment: when i copy this code i get following error:'IE11' has already been specified and must be unique. i comment the lines cause this error my problem solved.