# IIS 8 asp.net 4.0/4.5/4.6.1 internet explorer compatibility

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis-8

I have a web server running  Windows Server 2012/ IIS8. 
When opening the webpage locally (Internet Explorer on the server) it works like a charm, saving cookies and all.
On the client's pcs it works only in Chrome and mozilla, while on smartphones (safari and chrome) it does not work at all.

I tried:

1. checking for latest updates from windows update in the server
2. aspnet_regbrowsers.exe -i like described here (http://rikter.com/articles/2013/12/internet-explorer-11-and-asp-net/)
3. in one client machine disabled all seccurity settings and accepting all cookies from all sites.
4. run the MICROSOFT .NET FRAMEWORK REPAIR TOOL on the server
5. updading app_browsers folder with browsers definition from here ([App_Browsers definition file for IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417420/app-browsers-definition-file-for-ie-11))
6. clearing all saved data in client's pc and stored cookies forms etc.
   7.change the project's target framework from 4.0 to 4.6.1

None of the above solved the problem.

I tracked the response with fiddler, and they contain the cookie. But the cookie folder of IE is empty.

Comment: What are the cookie settings in IE? (In a corporate environment IE settings can be configured via group policy.)

Comment: i tried it with all the settings combination (medium-low, low, none and enabled/ disabled the protected checkbox )

Comment: Not the security zone level but the privacy settings: Internet Options | Privacy | Advanced. Can be used to block some or all cookies. Also, if you run with the dev tools options are any JS errors shown?

Comment: @Richard it is accept in both of the options. no js errors are shown only this `perf_trace {"name": "e2e", "parent": "PageEvents.BIGPIPE_ONLOAD"}: 5.022,913ms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the cause of this problem was the time of the webServer. 
I was 3hrs behind and that caused (for some reason in explorer only) the cookie to expire right after it was set.