# _doPostBack not defined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have written the script dynamically using string builder as follows

```
public static void ShowMessage1(ENUM_MessageType pMessageType, string pMessage, Button c)
    {
StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
        strScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"").Append("/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js").Append("\"></script>");
        strScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"").Append("/Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js").Append("\"></script>");
        strScript.Append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"").Append("/Styles/msgBoxLight.css").Append("\" />");
        strScript.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        strScript.Append("(function example()");
        strScript.Append("{");
        strScript.Append("$.msgBox({");
        strScript.Append("title:'" + lMessageType + "'");
        strScript.Append(",");
        strScript.Append("content:'" + pMessage + "'");
        strScript.Append(",");
        strScript.Append("type:'" + lOptionType + "'");
        strScript.Append(",");
        strScript.Append("buttons: [{ value: 'Yes' }, { value: 'No'}],");
        strScript.Append("success: function (result) {");
        strScript.Append("if(result == 'Yes'){");
        strScript.Append("javascript:_doPostBack('" + c.ClientID + "','');");
        strScript.Append("}");
        strScript.Append("}");
        strScript.Append("});");
        strScript.Append("})();");
        strScript.Append("</script>");
        if (page != null && !page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert"))
        {
            page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(enumClass), "info", strScript.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am getting the exception as `ReferenceError: _doPostBack is not defined` can some one help me

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's two underscores (`__doPostBack` instead of `_doPostBack`)

Comment: try adding one underscore to _doPostBack.  make it __doPostBack

Answer (score 1):

Its should `javascript` currently you have

```
strScript.Append("avascript:_doPostBack('" + c.ClientID + "','');");
```

It should be:

```
strScript.Append("javascript:__doPostBack('" + c.ClientID + "','');");
```

Missing `j` in front. Also make sure that its `__` not a single underscore.

Comment: Further it should be __doPostBack

Comment: @Deepak, does having a double underscore `__` solves the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing an underscore on your `__doPostBack()` call.

Also, take a look at the `success` in your rendered JS:

```
(function example() {
    $.msgBox({
        title : 'INFORMATION',
        content : 'I am from client side',
        type : 'confirm',
        buttons : [{
                value : 'Yes'
            }, {
                value : 'No'
            }
        ],
        success : function (result) {
            if (result == 'Yes') {
                javascript : __doPostBack('Button1', ''); // <--- this line
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

If you are just trying to call a postback there, get rid of the `javascript :` so that it reads like this:

```
strScript.Append("__doPostBack('" + c.ClientID + "','');");
```

Also, according to the answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480362/dopostback-is-not-defined), make sure there is an ASP.NET WebControl rendered to the page. `__doPostBack()` is automatically included on the page when a WebControl is rendered. So, if you on't have one on the page, there's a chance that the `__doPostBack()` method could be missing.

Comment: Still same issue I am getting in firefox

Comment: @Dotnet, What's the script look like after it gets rendered to the page?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/msgBoxLight.css" /><script type="text/javascript">(function example(){$.msgBox({title:'INFORMATION',content:'I am from client side',type:'confirm',buttons: [{ value: 'Yes' }, { value: 'No'}],success: function (result) {if(result == 'Yes'){javascript:__doPostBack('Button1','');}}});})();</script>`

Comment: can you check for any missing </script> tag

Comment: Hi I even tired in that way with out javascript in that line but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have any asp.net server side postback controls on the page the “_doPostBack not defined” error will be thrown on the client. To avoid the described error you can try adding following lines of code into the page load event:

```
protected override void OnPreLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);

        base.OnPreLoad(e);
    }
```

The GetPostBackEventReference returns a string that can be used in a client event to cause postback to the server

The other approach is to add hidden asp:Button which will register the same scripts as GetPostBackEventReference method.